# Learning 'dynamic' javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Little help for a javascript noob please...
I have this in a .js file on my web server:

```
Q=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:document.getSelection(); alert(Q);
```

I highlight some text on a web page (tested with Chrome and firefox) and paste this into the address bar:

```
javascript:(function(){vara=document.createElement('SCRIPT');a.type='text/javascript';a.src='http://automatethegame.com/js/test.js?';document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(vara)})();
```

it appears to do nothing.  Any assistance or suggestions would be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between `var` and `a`:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement('SCRIPT');a.type='text/javascript';a.src='http://automatethegame.com/js/test.js?';document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)})();
```